# How do I add subsubsets title on x-axis in matlab plotting?

Tags: matlab, plot

I don't know how to do the subsubsets of title on x-axis in matlab plotting on this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot].

How do I do it?

Comment: I don't understand what a subsubset is. Do you mean change the `X` and `Y` text?

Comment: No, I mean it is like on the x-axis, there are three lines, the first line from left to right is X and Y, the second line consists of 0.01 and 0.1, and the third one includes XP and YP. How can I do like that ? Thanks.

Comment: Oh you want to add 3 lines of text below your graph?

Comment: In addition, subsubset means that XP consists of a set of 0.01 and 0.1, and each includes a set of X and Y. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It's correct. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to use the editing window after plotting a "normal" bar chart. Then, I added manually the second and third lines using text boxes. It turns out that the annotations on added figures will not be identical on alignment since I have to add the text boxes for each figure. So, if using the code, it's gonna be identical for all figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get more control over the elements you are plotting, you can specify the position/dimension of the axes object in which to display your graph so that you can leave room below for text elements. If you are using 'normalized' coordinates that should be similar among multiple figures having the same number of graphs.

Example:

```
clear
clc
close all

%// Create figure and axes --> set its position as you like
f = figure();

%// Note the use of normalized units inside the axes
hAxes = axes('Position',[.05 .2 .9 .7],'Units','normalized');

y = [2 4 6; 3 4 5;1 2 4 ];
b = bar(y);

%// Add title
title('This is a nice title','FontSize',16)

%// First line of text: XTIck label property of axex
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'X';'Y';'Z'},'FontSize',16)

%//Query axis limits in x and y
x_limit = xlim;
y_limit = ylim;

%//Add custom text
text(x_limit(1)*3,-.8,'0.01','FontSize',14)
text(x_limit(1)*5,-.8,'0.1','FontSize',14)

text(x_limit(1)*4,-1.4,'XP','FontSize',14)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping. I really appreciate it.